# java webcam adjust shutter speed

Tags: java, performance, webcam, shutter

I want to (manually) adjust the "shutter speed" of my webcam with Java code.

1. Is it possible to do this (with java) ?
2. How do I realize it ?

Extra info:

- Windows vista and NetBeans IDE 7.3.1
- Webcam : Logitech webcam pro 4000
- Driver : Quickcam v11
- Language : java
- Library : LTI-CIVIL with example code for image capturing
- I think I need to adjust somewhere the time between the command for
  the camera to collect light and stop collecting light. (half thinking of 
  an SLR camera).

Answer (score 1):

There are certain **available API's** that can be used **to control your webcam** using java.

- **Java Media Framework (JMF)**

The Java Media Framework API (JMF) enables audio, video and other time-based media to be added to applications and applets built on Java technology. This optional package, which can capture, playback, stream, and transcode multiple media formats, extends the Java 2 Platform, Standard Edition (J2SE) for multimedia developers by providing a powerful toolkit to develop scalable, cross-platform technology.

- **Freedom for Media in Java (FMJ)**

FMJ is an open-source project with the goal of providing an alternative to Java Media Framework (JMF), while remaining API-compatible with JMF. It aims to produce a single API/Framework which can be used to capture, playback, process, and stream media across multiple platforms.Since FMJ is API-compatible with latest JMF, you may use existing JMF codes and run them.

- **Xuggler**

Xuggler is the easy way to uncompress, modify, and re-compress any media file (or stream) from Java. This is more widely used for manipulation of media files and related operations.

You can refer the following links:

- [Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html)
- [Freedom for Media in Java](http://fmj-sf.net/)
- [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler)

You can find tons of tutorials on them. I'm sure you can figure out an efficient way to control the shutter speed of your webcam using any of these API's. :)